# change Angular Filter Comparator boolean on runtime

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

Is it possible to change the angular comparator boolean on runtime? Like having a checkbox which changes the comparator to true or false.

```
<input id="strictSearch" ng-value="strictSearch" type="checkbox">
<tr data-ng-repeat="item in (filteredList = (allSerialNumbers | filter:search:strictSearch)) | orderBy: sortType :sortReverse track by $index"
                         class="table-row" ng-if="item.serialNumber != ''" id="{{item.appointmentId}}">
```

This example does not work. So I'm looking for a solution. Is there a simple way to do it? Or do I have to write my own filter?

Comment: Which comparator/operator?

Comment: {{ filter_expression | filter : expression : comparator : anyPropertyKey}}
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Comment: Ok i think I got a solution....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just had a stupid syntax error using ng-value instead of ng-model on the checkbox.